# No implementation found for void eu.kudan.kudan.ARTexture2D.loadFromPathN(java.lang.String)

Tags: kudan

It seems that there is no implementation of method that uploads an ARTexture2D from path on Android. But there is a declaration of ARTexture2D.loadFromPath. Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the latest version, that was added last release.
https://wiki.kudan.eu/KudanAR_Android_Version_History